# Why does Java not allow me to use OAuth2Native methods here?

Tags: java, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

Ok, so I'm trying to build a simple "Hello World"-type program that gets data from the Google Analytics API. I'm following the tutorial here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

My code is below. There's no main method yet, I'm just trying to get authorized and get a Analytics Service Object set up. I'm working in Netbeans. I've downloaded an imported the classes from Google listed at the top of the code. My problem is that Netbeans gives me a "cannot find symbol" on the `OAuth2Native.authorize()` in the first line of initializeAnalytics and on `Analytics.builder()` a few lines below that. I assume there's some class I need to import, but I can't seem to find it and wonder if that's not the problem at all.

Many thanks in advance.

```
package helloanalyticsapi;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.*;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloAnalyticsApi {

 // Global instance of the HTTP transport.
 private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

 // Global instance of the JSON factory.
 private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

 private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
    Credential credential = OAuth2Native.authorize(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new LocalServerReceiver(),
    Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY));

    Analytics analytics;
    analytics = Analytics.builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
        .setApplicationName("Hello-Analytics-API-Sample")
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
        .build();

    return analytics;

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {   

 }
}
```

Comment: It's telling you you haven't imported those classes. Some quick googling finds a number of people complaining that their API docs / examples are pretty broken. The only place I can even find that class is here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/shared/cmdline/oauth2/OAuth2Native.java?repo=samples&r=89662bd8ab341647b3f0aab8ed6a4fb444f478c2

Comment: Right, ok, thanks. I found that page as well. But am I missing something or shouldn't that class be part of a larger package? I don't see any way to download! (Or do I create my own .java file by copying and pasting that code?)

Comment: Which java use case is this for? J2EE, command line, or Android?

Comment: Hey Brett, this was Java Enterprise Edition.